# Need help setting up Docker Home Media server

Tags: networking, 18.04, docker, zfs, mediaserver

So I am attempting to put together a home media server on Ubuntu 18.04. I have done this in a VM on a Windows machine, but a recently built a new gaming rig, and am repurposing the old one into a server. Here is my plan, and then the problems. This is on baremetal fyi.

I have a 128gb ssd acting as / and /home at /dev/sda. On here I have used https://github.com/GhostWriters/DockSTARTer

to get containers up and running. Everything works well for a day or two, until Radarr, Sonarr, or other containers begin to give me ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. I am trying to make sense of this and believe it to be because docker has dynamic dns, but I am not very familiar with networking. I did not have this problem when running in a VM, which was running in windows with bridged adapter on oracle Virtualbox. My thoughts on getting around this was going to a hypervisor and was considering proxmox.

Issue two: I have four 8 tb drives in a Zfs RaidZ1. I have this mounted under tank, and used the default dockstarter app to point the data to the drive at /tank/medialibrary/movies and /tank/medialibrary/tv. I set these up in Radarr and Sonarr. It shows my 20.4 TB of storage, and appears to be sending the data there, but I just filled up my /home file on the /dev/sda last night. I am using transmissionvpn for torrents. I believe this must be a problem with the /dev/sda and Zpool not being able to share data. I have considered just making the boot drive into a Zpool, but some people don't seem to like that approach as ZFS is not standard in Linux.

Any help and ideas of how to make this work are appreciated!

Comment: It's been my experience that docker is just garbage at this point and really never be used (that is until they can fix some major bugs...) That being said why exactly are you running docker? Why not just set up the containers yourself? Had you done that rather than using the automated script you would have a better understanding of the containers and likely be able to debug this yourself..

Comment: Fair point, it just worked when I did it on the virtual machine, so that’s what I went back to. How would you recommend setting up containers?

Comment: Again I'm not a huge fan of `docker` you can always check out `systemd-nspawn`. But I'm still uncertain as to why you want to containerize things (not that it's a problem)

Comment: I'm a Docker aficionado, but I also wonder why you use Docker for this.

Comment: It was just what I first tried and it worked. Considering going to Proxmox and giving that a try. I just want to easily get things setup without running into permission errors etc.

Comment: @Alschmitt44 wrote "... without running into permission errors etc." http://xyproblem.info/ ....